# redirection of stdout output to one of the serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, stdout

I am writing a python program to test a hardware. This hardware prints log messages on serial port. This is working properly.

Now they have a emultor for this hardware which runs as a windows application and prints same logs on windows terminal.

Wanted to know is there any way I can redirect the logs from windows terminal to serial port so that whatever program i have written will automatically work for windows emulator too

Thank in Advance

Comment: Can you just redirect when executing the emulator `whatever > COM1` or similar?

Comment: Thanks jon for quick response. I have created a virtual comport using com0com. COM20 and COM21 are virtual com ports. Whatever input i get to COM20 will be redirected to COM21. Now when I do emul.exe > COM20 I am not seeing any out on seeing any output on COM21. if i do emul.exe > file.txt I get all the output in a file. Do you know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect python stdout to a handle. I've used the below to put this into a file.

I expect you could set sys.stdout to a serial.Serial object to have prints write to the handle.

```
sys.stdout= open(file, 'w')

# script here
print "test"

# Flush 
sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
```